# how do I install supersu (not systemless) in Samsung?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

I try desperately install supersu in my Samsung s7 Edge (g935f) from TWRP flashing supersu2.76.zip in traditional way (not systemless).

After startup from supersu app I see "install supersu into /system not available in system-less root mode"

Comment: Pretty sure stock Nougat requires a systemless install or it will bootloop. What is the problem that you need to try to install it into /system?

Comment: because I have an app that wants system mode root.

Comment: The app must be outdated... Go back to the developer, system based rooting isn't possible in stock Marshmallow or Nougat, so at least 18 months ago it has been the "new" standard. Lollipop was the last version that supported traditional rooting by placing su in /system.

Comment: exactly app is knox reset (counter) available on Google play. developer sent to me a version of supersu that should works as system-mode root. but (for now I hope) does not work.

Comment: I can't find your app, but assume it is similar to this one https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/disable-knox-reset-knox-counter-to-0x0-t3414890 and it doesn't work in Marshmallow and newer, it requires Android  4.x or 5.x to work. My understanding that the KNOX flag is now permanently tripped on newer devices, no going back or undoing it as it is not a software marker any longer.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.venus342.donate

Comment: According to their website and app listing it should work. I would contact the developer at this point. There is no way on a stock ROM to do a traditional system based root on Marshmallow, so what you are asking in your question is not possible to my knowledge.